# How to get an exception thrown from another application in Java?

Tags: java, exception, runtime, exec

I have the following code which prints the output of the DataIntegrationV8.jar to the JTextArea. Is it possible to print an exception thrown by that program in the same JTextArea?

```
protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Process process;
        InputStream iStream;
        try {
            //run the DataIntegration.jar
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar DataIntegrationV8.jar sample.xml");
            istream = process.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException("Error executing DataIntegrationV8.jar");
        }

        //get the output of the DataIntegration.jar and put it to the 
        //DataIntegrationStarter.jar form
        InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(iStream);
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
        String line;

        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            jtaAbout.append(line + "\n");
        }
        Thread.sleep(1);
        return 42;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default exception stacktraces are displayed to `System.err`. You could include the output from the `ErrorStream` to the `JTextArea`.

```
BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
String errorLine = null;
while ((errorLine = error.readLine()) != null) {
    jtaAbout.append(errorLine + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the error  code returned by the program and it it is not zero, you know the output is a java stacktrace as the program terminated ...... poorly.